# How to change the solution structure in TFS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, code-organization

How to restructure a solution that is currently being maintained by source control? I need to create a couple of folders and move the existing projects to folder and another folder to maintain dependencies etc..

so, shall I make the changes in source control itself? or from my local machine? I am facing it difficult to make changes locally (where I mapped the project to source control) and sync (check-in) the changes as the structure itself is completely get modified.

So I am thinking the changes has to be made at source control? Pl suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

**It is easier to do this in TFS for a few reasons:**

- You will create a historical change set of what was moved or renamed, vs. doing locally you will be forced to do adds/deletes
- TFS will automatically move the folders on your machine and update the mapped paths.
- If you also need to rename anything (which you didnt mention, but it can be considered part of code organization), TFS also updates solution files appropriately when you rename projects, so you don't have to remove and re-add projects to your solution that includes renamed projects.

The only note is that often you will have files and folders such as `bin` and `obj` folders that are not in TFS, and those will not get moved by TFS, leaving half empty directories. You will need to clean those up manually on your machine.

Comment: to remove the empty folders I cleared my local workspace and then got latest on the whole project.